# Parsing part of XML file

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

So i am stuck on this for quite some time now. I use libxml2 and it works great for another part in the code but i cant seem to figure this one out and its bugging me like crazy.

I have this xml code:

```
<MetaCommandSet>
  <MetaCommand name="ChangeSystemInterval">
    <ArgumentList>
      <Argument name="Interval" argumentTypeRef="UnsignedByteType"></Argument>
    </ArgumentList>
  </MetaCommand>
```

Now what i want is the name of the command and its arguments. This means that it has to stay in the same meta command so that i can collect al the arguments and than save this to for example a struct.

Code snippet:

```
   for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next)
   {
    DATA TM_tmp;
    COMMAND TC_tmp;

    if(!xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, "MetaCommand"))
    {
        TC_tmp.functionName = malloc(strlen((xmlGetProp(cur_node, "name") + 1)));
        TC_tmp.functionName = xmlGetProp(cur_node, "name");
        printf("Name: %s\n",TC_tmp.functionName);
        /*
          It now needs to keep looping this so i get every argument but it cant find any childs after argumentList

        */
    }

    createArray(cur_node->children);
```

I am nog getting further than getting the MetaCommand name. I am already looping threw all elements and if its a MetaCommand element i want to proceed with what i stated above.

Please give me some ideas

Comment: You might like to show the code snippets where you got stuck.

Comment: dont see how that matters because i got almost nothing. But ill add it EDIT: added :)

Comment: The `->next` member points to the next *sibling* of the node. You have to use `->children` to get the first child of a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taken from one of my source coeds. You have to dive one level deeper than me, i have < pricing>< price age_group="">< EUR>...< /EUR>< /pricing>< /price>

```
{
while (cur != NULL) {
  if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "pricing") == 0) {
    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;

    while (cur != NULL) {
      if (xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *) "price") == 0) {
        xmlNodePtr node = cur->xmlChildrenNode;

        if (*kopf == NULL) {
          *kopf = (Pricing *)HeapMalloc(sizeof(Pricing), "Pricing", 0);
          ret = *kopf;
        } else {
          ret->next = (Pricing *)HeapMalloc(sizeof(Pricing), "Pricing", 0);
          ret = ret->next;
        }

        parseAttribut(cur,      "age_group",        &(ret->age_group),   fehler);
        parseElement(doc, node, "EUR",              &(ret->price),       fehler);
      }
      cur = cur->next;
    }
    break;
  }
  cur = cur->next;
}
}


void parseAttribut(xmlNodePtr node, const xmlChar *str, xmlChar **dest, short muss, short *fehler)
{
  *dest = xmlGetProp(node, str);
  return;
}

void parseElement(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, const xmlChar *str, xmlChar **dest,  short muss, short *fehler)
{
  short found = FALSE;

  while (node) {
    if (xmlStrcmp(node->name, str) == 0) {
      *dest = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, node->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
      found = TRUE;
      break;
    }
    node = node->next;
  }
  return;
}
```